# How to synchronize Oracle data with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

An Oracle11g database on one machine with unique IP, and a SQL Server 2008 database on another machine.

A table X in Oracle has some columns, same as the columns of table Y in SQL Server.

Now I want to synchronize the column's values in `X` with the column's values in `Y`, that is (maybe it is wordy!), when values changed in X, so it is **IMMEDIATELY** and automatically to update the values in Y without any more manual operation in SQL Server.

How to get this done!?

THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

You can link the two databases either via an Oracle Gateway and a database link in the Oracle database or via a Linked Server in SQL Server instance.

If you really want to have two exact copies of the table one in each database, rather than storing it in one location and accessing it directly from both databases, and updates must be immediate (ish because immediate is really only available in the one table scenario) then you'll need to use a trigger to update the other table via the link.

Comment: NOT exactly copyies of the table in each database!! Just share some (not all) fields each other! I just not sure a trigger in Oracle  really can update table which in MSSQL or not. just recently I read sth about Oracle Gateway, and it takes time!

Comment: Yes, a trigger can issue an update or insert statement over a database link and this can be via a gateway to SQL (the trigger won't know or care about that part).  Gateways do take a little effort to set-up but they are little more than installing a new home with a listener and adding an extra bit of config to point the listener to the remote (SQL Server in your case) database.